# Fibonacci bit string representation

Tags: java, sorting, compression, sequence, fibonacci

I am programming a Fibonacci representation of chars that takes a string that was input, and will output the bit string form of the string, based off the frequency of occurence for each letter (hence . For example if one types: 
**"carnegie mellon"**
Then the output would be:

**Header / 01011 / 1011 / 000011 / 011 / 11 / 100011 / 00011 / 11 / 001011 / 010011 / 11 / 0011 / 0011 / 10011 / 011**

In our assignment, we also were required to calculate the frequency of chars, and rank them. I have done this part, but am confused on converting these char's into a fibonacci representation (My program does output the fib sequence according to rank).

In case anyone is confused by what the bit string representation means, here is a quick example:

2,7,4,3 as f(n) would equal 10,1010,101,100
My teacher wants us to append a 1 to each of them which would then equal 011,01011,1011,0011

**Here is my code:**

```
  import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
public class Freq
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        //read input stream
         BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter your String");
            String line = in.readLine();
            HashMap<Character,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
            for(char c : line.toCharArray()) {                  //cycle through char array
                Integer count = counts.get(c);                  
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 0;
                }
                counts.put(c, ++count);                         //count increments and places into map
            }
            List<Entry<Character,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(counts.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<Character,Integer>>() {
                //@Override
                public int compare(Entry<Character, Integer> o1,
                        Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
                    return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
                }
            });
            for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry : list) {
                System.out.println("The character "+entry.getKey() +" has occured for "+ entry.getValue()+" times");
            }

            int index = 0;                          //fibanocci base case
            for(Entry<Character,Integer> entry2 : list){
                System.out.println(fibonacci(index));
                index++;
            }
    }
    public static long fibonacci(int i){
        if(i == 0){
            return 0;       //base case
        }
        if(i <= 2){
            return 1;       //base case
        }
        long fibTerm = fibonacci( i -1) + fibonacci(i-2);
        return fibTerm;
    }
}
```

**Example output:**

```
Enter your String
this is a string
The character   has occured for 3 times
The character s has occured for 3 times
The character i has occured for 3 times
The character t has occured for 2 times
The character g has occured for 1 times
The character r has occured for 1 times
The character a has occured for 1 times
The character n has occured for 1 times
The character h has occured for 1 times
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
```

**How do I get my calculated fib # representations into this bitstring form of the fibonacci sequence?**
Let me know if I can clear anything up or add information to the question to help you guys fully understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your question is how to print a number's binary representation backwards?

Comment: @Njol Not binary, but a sort of 'fibonacci' binary representation. Each digit place corresponds to 1,2,3,5,8,13 and so forth. So fibonacci 7 = 1010 because 5+2 = 7.

Comment: To encode an integer N:
Find the largest Fibonacci number equal to or less than N; subtract this number from N, keeping track of the remainder.
If the number subtracted was the ith Fibonacci number F(i), put a 1 in place i−2 in the code word (counting the left most digit as place 0).
Repeat the previous steps, substituting the remainder for N, until a remainder of 0 is reached.
Place an additional 1 after the rightmost digit in the code word.

Comment: @MariusŽilėnas I just found this explanation on wikipedia. However, I am stuck on the coding aspect of this. I do actually understand the algorithm, it's just translating into code is the problem I am having. I am going to come back to this after I think about it for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I added some functionality to the code:

Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_coding , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class Freq {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
        throws IOException {

        /* read input stream */
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));

        /* System.out.println("Enter your String"); */
        String line = "carnegie mellon"; //in.readLine();

        Map<Character,Integer> counts = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

        int ci = 0;
        for(char c : line.toCharArray()) { /* cycle through char array */
            ci = counts.containsKey(c)
                ? counts.get(c) + 1
                : 1;
            counts.put(c, ci);  /* count increments and places into map */
        }

        List<Entry<Character,Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>(
                counts.entrySet());
        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<Character,Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Entry<Character, Integer> o1,
                    Entry<Character, Integer> o2) {
                return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
            }
        });

        Map<Character, Integer> sorted = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        int i = 1;
        for (Entry<Character,Integer> entry : list) {
            System.out.println(
                    "The character "      + entry.getKey() 
                    + " has occured for " + entry.getValue() 
                    + " times");
            /** count occurencies of character */
            sorted.put(
                    entry.getKey(), i++);
        }


        System.out.print("Header / ");
        for (String s : encode(line, sorted)) {
            System.out.print(s + " / ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Encode a given string.
     */
    public static List<String> encode(
            String text, Map<Character, Integer> counts) {
        List<String> encoded = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) { 
            encoded.add(
                    bitSetAsString(
                        numberToBits(
                            counts.get(c))));
        }
        return encoded;
    }

    /** 
     * Convert number to bits
     */
    public static BitSet numberToBits(long n) {
        /** next Fibonacci */
        long nextf = 0;
        int  i     = 0;
        /** remainder */
        long rem   = n;
        /** 
         * Fibonacci numbers that encode the given n.
         */
        List<Integer> fibs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        /** temporary Fibonacci number */
        long tf    ;
        /** index of Fibonacci number */
        int  fi    ;

        do {
            /** Find largest Fibonacci smaller than rem. */
            i     = 2;
            fi    = i;
            tf    = Fibonacci.fibonacci(i);
            nextf = tf; 
            while (tf < rem) {
                tf = Fibonacci.fibonacci(i+1);
                if (tf > rem) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    nextf = tf;
                    fi    = i+1;
                }
                i++;
            }

            rem = rem - nextf;
            /** If found Fibonacci number collect it. */
            if (Fibonacci.isFibonacci(nextf)) {
                fibs.add(fi);
            }
        } while (rem > 0);

        /** make a bitset represenation */
        BitSet encoded = new BitSet();
        for(Integer j : fibs) {
            encoded.set(j-2);
        }
        /** place an additional 1 after the rightmost digit in the code */
        encoded.set(
                encoded.length());

        return encoded;
    }

    public static String bitSetAsString(BitSet bs) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < bs.length(); i++) {
            sb.append(
                    bs.get(i) 
                    ? '1'
                    : '0');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    static class Fibonacci {
        public static long fibonacci(long i){
            return (0 == i || 1 == i)
                    ? i 
                    : (fibonacci(i-1) + fibonacci(i-2));
        }

        public static boolean isFibonacci(long n) {
            long i     = 0;
            long nextf = fibonacci(i);
            while (nextf < n) {
                nextf = fibonacci(++i);
            }
            return nextf == n;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! When I get to a compiler I will analyze and try this out! Those Wiki sources are surprisingly very informative!